# How to get chart from Excel in onedrive using graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

While trying to get Charts from a Worksheet, I am getting an "Internal Error" response.

I am issuing a GET request where `demo.xlsx` is my excel file and `CHART2` is the name of the sheet:

```
/v1.0/me/drive/root:/demo.xlsx:/workbook/worksheets/CHART2/charts
```

Furthermore, if I have no charts in the sheet, I don't receive an error response, only an empty array (as expected).

Interestingly enough I can get a Chart if I know it's name using either of these two paterns:

```
('Chart-Name')/Image(width=400, height=200, fittingMode='
```

```
/charts/Chart-Name/name
```